# Undefined variable in Laravel trying to post source ID route

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, variables

Currently Working on building out a news api behind a dashboard. I have just recently started getting the error Undefined variable: sourceId (View: C:\Laravel8Auth\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php).
Ive gone everywhere that has source Id and I cant see to figure out what it could be.
Here are some of the codes necessary, im using Laravel 8.x with JetStream Im fairly new at this just wanted to mess around.
web php

```js
`<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\Api;
use App\Http\Controllers\ApiController;

///Route::get('/', [ApiController::class,'displayNews']);
///Route::get('/fetchNewsFromSource', [ApiController::class, 'fetchNewsFromSource'])->name('fetchNewsFromSource');
///Route::post('/sourceId', 'ApiController@displayNews');
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@displayNews');
Route::post('sourceId', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@displayNews');

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
`
```

Dashboard php

```js
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
     <title>News Application with Laravel</title>
     <!-- Fonts -->
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 
     <!-- Styles -->
     <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="appendDivNews">
     <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">News Around the World</a>
     </nav>
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     <section id="content" class="section-dropdown">
         <p class="select-header"> Select a news source: </p>
         <label class="select">
             <select name="news_sources" id="news_sources">
                 <option value="{{$sourceId}} : {{$sourceName}}">{{$sourceName}}</option>
                 @foreach ($newsSources as $newsSource)
                     <option value="{{$newsSource['id']}} : {{$newsSource['name'] }}">{{$newsSource['name']}}</option>
                 @endforeach
             </select>
 
         </label>
         <object id="spinner" data="spinner.svg" type="image/svg+xml" hidden></object>
     </section>
     <div id="news">
         <p> News Source : {{$sourceName}} </p>
 
 
         <section class="news">
             @foreach($news as $selectedNews)
 
                 <article>
                     <img src="{{$selectedNews['urlToImage']}}" alt=""/>
                     <div class="text">
                         <h1>{{$selectedNews['title']}}</h1>
                         <p style="font-size: 14px">{{$selectedNews['description']}} <a href="{{$selectedNews['url']}}"
                                                                                        target="_blank">
                                 <small>read more...</small>
                             </a></p>
                         <div style="padding-top: 5px;font-size: 12px">
                             Author: {{$selectedNews['author'] ? : "Unknown" }}</div>
                         @if($selectedNews['publishedAt'] !== null)
                             <div style="padding-top: 5px;">Date
                                 Published: {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($selectedNews['publishedAt'])->format('l jS \\of F Y ') }}</div>
                         @else
                             <div style="padding-top: 5px;">Date Published: Unknown</div>
                         @endif
 
                     </div>
                 </article>
             @endforeach
         </section>
 
 
     </div>
 </div>
 
 </body>
 <!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Scripts -->
 <script src="{{ asset('js/site.js') }}"></script>
 
 </html>
```

apicontroller.php supposed to grab from this to get the news api

```js
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Api;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function displayNews(Request $request)
    {
        $response = $this->determineMethodHandler($request);
        $apiModel = new Api();
        $response['news'] = $apiModel->fetchNewsFromSource($response['sourceId']);
        $response['newsSources'] = $this->fetchAllNewsSources();
        return view('dashboard', $response);
    }

    /**
     * @param $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function determineMethodHandler($request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('get')) {
            $response['sourceName'] = config('app.default_news_source');
            $response['sourceId'] = config('app.default_news_source_id');
        } else {
            $request->validate([
                'source' => 'required|string',
            ]);
            $split_input = explode(':', $request->source);
            $response['sourceId'] = trim($split_input[0]);
            $response['sourceName'] = trim($split_input[1]);
        }
        return $response;
    }
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function fetchAllNewsSources()
    {
        $response = Cache::remember('allNewsSources', 22 * 60, function () {
            $api = new Api;
            return $api->getAllSources();
        });
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: `<option value="{{$sourceId}}`   found it in 1 second ... nothing is passing that variable to that view apparently and you are not either ... what is that supposed to be? where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: @lagbox will update with the controller im using sorry its from ApiController

Comment: well you have a `get` route, `/dashboard`, that returns this view and doesn't pass any data .. it is in the routes you are showing above

Comment: Im a little confused on what your saying

Comment: look at the routes you posted, the one for `/dashboard` is returning the view named `dashboard` and is not passing any data to it ... i don't understand what part of that you don't understand

Comment: I UNDERSTAND NOW WOW (not being sarcastic) thank you! I was looking in the wrong area now i see what im doing

Comment: np, good luck and have fun

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an array with variables to views

`view('dashboard', ["sourceId" => 1, /* and so on */]);`

I can't understand what are you doing there.

Comment: im Trying to pass newsAPI to a dashboard